# Java Swing - Cycle through an array with up- and down-buttons and print it in a textfield

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I making a java-Swing application that allows you to add, remove, update etc. personal info to an array of objects, and i want to be able to cycle through the array with up- and down-buttons and printing out the firstnames in a jTextField.
The code i have right now, kind of works:

```
private void jbtnUPActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        if(counter == 0){
        jtfName.setText(nameArray[counter].getName());
        }
        if(counter > 0){
        counter--;
        jtfName.setText(nameArray[counter].getName());
        }
}                                      

private void jbtnDownActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

if (counter < index)
        counter++;
        jtfName.setText(nameArray[counter].getName());
}
```

The index int is just an int to keep track of how many elements are in the array. With this code i'm able to cycle through each object and printing the firstname to the textfield. But right now it's not optimal. Here's what i want to do:

The first time you click either up- or -downbutton in the app, i want to clear the textfield and print out the FIRST element, and then you should be able to cycle through them normally. Right now my up-button works, if you click it first it prints out the name in the first object.

If you first click the down-button, it skips to the second object [1].I'm aware of this but have no idea how to fix it. I want it to be the first object and then be able to continue the cycling.

I hope my question makes sense, any help is appreciated.

//N

Comment: Wouldn't a JComboBox or JSpinner provide the same functionality?

Comment: There are better components/methods for achieving this, that produce a better user experience, have a look at [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 2):

> The first time you click either up- or -downbutton in the app, i want
>   to clear the textfield and print out the FIRST element, and then you
>   should be able to cycle through them normally.

You need to store this initial state.  Try initializing `counter` to -1.  This should fix it for your down button (since `counter++` will set that to 0), but you'll have to make a change for your up button.  For example:

```
private void jbtnUPActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
    if (counter < 0) {
        counter = 0
    }

    if (counter == 0) {
        jtfName.setText(nameArray[counter].getName());
    } else if(counter > 0) {
        counter--;
        jtfName.setText(nameArray[counter].getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks alot! Never thought of setting counter to -1!

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, you're `actionPerformed` methods should do one thing, change the `counter`, they should then call another method (`setIndex`?) which passes the `counter` value to it, this method should validate the value (make sure it's within range) and then (probably through another method) update the UI.

Your `actionPerformed` methods should use the current "known" "index", for example `setIndex(getIndex() - 1)`. This way you generate simple, re-usable code.  You can now move between records by calling `setIndex`, maybe even using a `JSlider` or some other navigation device, without having to reinvent the wheel.  You also isolate responsibility and reduce code duplication

Having said all that, there are better components/methods for achieving this, that produce a better user experience, have a look at [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)